# i keep getting a wrong date (1970-01-01) after adding days to an existing date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image: when i use $leaveDays]i fetched a number of days from the database to add to an inputed date from my form but it keeps giving a wrong output as date 1970-01-01

```
$newTime = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($all_leave->date_from.' + '.$leaveDays.' days'));
```

and for my $leaveDays

```
$leaveDays = leaveType::all()->where('leave_type','=',$all_leave->leave_type)->pluck('leave_days');
```

Comment: i notice the error is from the line becauee if i dd($newTime) i get the wrong date 01-01-1970

Comment: when any wrong date then you will get `1970-01-01` as date

Comment: Try this :$newTime = date('d-m-Y', (strtotime($all_leave->date_from) + ($leaveDays * 24 *60)));

Comment: Show us what `dd($all_leave->date_from)` outputs

Comment: @krylov123 that gave a correct out put as inputed.

Comment: @yasin Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to number.. thats the error message i get

Comment: Show us what dd($all_leave->date_from) outputs

Comment: @NICANDIAS it is important for us to understand what exactly show `dd($all_leave->date_from)` and `dd($leaveDays)` because it's not only shows "inputed value" but also a type of object/variable.

Comment: and $leaveDays is number ?

Comment: @yasin Yes $leave days is number. the number of days i want to add to the date in $all_leave->date_from

Comment: and what about $all_leave->date_from ?

Comment: @kylov123 for $all_leave->date_from i got "2019-12-05" and for $leave days i got 32

Comment: @yasin $all_leave->date_from i got the date that was inputed in the form as requested 2019-12-05"

Comment: @NICANDIAS trace one-by-one. do half code and check it is working if yes than add anooher code : $newTime = date('d-m-Y', (strtotime($all_leave->date_from)));

Comment: When you have no value for `$leaveDays` then it will return date`01-01-1970`

Comment: @yasmin for $newTime = date('d-m-Y', (strtotime($all_leave->date_from))); i got "05-12-2019" as my output.

Comment: @omi how do i now get the value for $leavedays?

Comment: @yasin the problem is from the $leaveDays. i tried it half way and i got the wrong date.

Comment: @NICANDIAS you are getting $leaveDays as interger or as object value ?

Comment: just check you are not getting blank value for `$leaveDays`, if you are getting value form db then check in db it should not have null value in db

Comment: @yasmin have added the code for $leaveDays at the top. but i think am getting it as an object not integer.

Comment: $omi when i dd($leaveDays) i get whats in the database but when i dd($newTime) i get 01-01-1970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pluck` method retrieves all of the values for a given key. So return array of all values not single value but 
`strtotime()` needs days in number and you are providing array. So it is giving you wrong date. So you need to get first value from array as `leavedays` .

Just be sure that for leave days you will be only one value, if there are multiple values then you have to iterate if you needed else it will take only first value.

Try this

```
$leaveDays = leaveType::all()->where('leave_type','=',$all_leave->leave_type)->pluck('leave_days');

$leaveDays = empty($leaveDays[0]) ? 0 :  $leaveDays[0];

$newTime = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($all_leave->date_from.' + '.$leaveDays.' days'));
```

Comment: am not getting a null value for $leaveDays. if i dd($leaveDays) i use to get the number in the data base

Comment: but i dont know why its not working as dd($newTime)

Comment: did you get number value when you do `dd($leaveDays)`

Comment: i just did that and the image of wat i got has been attached at the top,Please help look into it.

Comment: yes it worked but i dont understand what you did can you please explain

Comment: I have explained in answer now

Comment: please is it possible to display the $leaveDays in my view according to whatever thats selected in the form that i got in $all_leave->leave_type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204182/discussion-between-nicandias-and-omi).

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon instead of directly data object

```
// $all_leave->date_from should be in standard mysql datetime format 2012-01-31 00:00:00
$newTime = Carbon::parse($all_leave->date_from)->addDays($leaveDays)->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: but am not using carbon in my code, how do i make the carbon work with it

Comment: @NICANDIAS If you use laravel 5.8 you have to import it on your file with use Carbon\Carbon;

Comment: @NICANDIAS laravel uses build in carbon package to maintain date and time. At the top of your controller file add this line `use Carbon\Carbon` and then use the provided solution